# Allow textarea to modify not only CSS, but JQuery too?

Tags: jquery, css, textarea

I have the following code that's linked to my textarea (link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgxFf/). The only problem is that when the users types *delete* I want an image to disappear. I know I'll need JQuery to do something like `$('#'pic').hide();` and I'll  need to add to the `$('#output').css` since I won't only be using css, but JQuery too. 
I'm not sure what to add or where.

```
var value = document.getElementById("userinput").value; 
      var unspeakables = ['shout', 'message', 'delete'],
        formatting = { 
            "shout" : {
                "color" : "red"
            },
            "message" : {
              "color" : "black" 
            }
          "delete" : {
          // JQuery...
        }
        };
    value = value.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + unspeakables.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b','gi'),
        function(matchedWord) {
            $('#output').css(formatting[matchedWord.toLowerCase()] || {});
            return '';
        }
    );
    $('#output').html(value);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, this should be as simple as

```
$('#userinput').click(function() {
    if ($('#userinput').val().match(/\bdelete\b/) { // or other regexp
        $('#pic').hide();
    }
    // insert tests for 'shout', 'message', etc here
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work with the code I have above. 
The code you posted is exactly what I was trying to do earlier, but I want to keep everything in the _unspeakables_ array. And have it do the same as the _formatting_ with the css. (only this time, I want to hide the picture and I figured JQuery would do the trick).

Comment: I think you've painted yourself into a corner here: you've set up that "formatting" object to only be able to modify the CSS of $('#output'); in this one case you need to modify $('#pic') instead.  You're going to have to add some conditional somewhere to tell your code which element it should be modifying.   Could do something like `{"shout": ...{"domElement": "#output", "css": {"color": "red"}}...` and then have your replace function use domElement to see which node to modify instead of hardcoding it, I guess.

Comment: But a series of if / else statements  would probably be a lot simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 I did just that in JQuery awhile ago and it worked great (it is much easier to maintain and makes more sense imo). Thanks for suggesting that!